Conrod small end lubrication
Would a side relief groove design used on piston pin bosses for oiling (Mahle's pin oiler relief grooves) work for a conrod's small end considering the engine uses piston oil squirters? I know Cosworth F1 conrods don't have oil holes and rely on the piston squirters.

maybe.  But what problem are you trying to solve?  I'm not away of small end conrod failures being a criticla item on engines.
